# Panda's not reading data from excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I posted a similar question last week but have come to the conclusion that it's not a problem with the code as such but a loss of data and I was wondering if anyone knows a fix or has experienced similar problems. I have tried saving the document as csv, xlsx and xls to see if this would resolve it but no change.

So my excel file is just a straight forward fairly small table with "Yes" and "No" values.

I know the code works because when I input this:

```
   df.loc[(df["Unnamed: 18"] == "Yes")]
```

I get the desired output of:

[image: return of code]

(If you cannot see the photo its returned the rows that were True)

However when I enter

```
df.loc[(df["Unnamed: 17"] == "Yes")]
```

[image: return of code]

(it returns no data if you cannot access the photo)

I get the same if I switch it to == "No".

It just does not want to read data from that column. I get sent several of these spreadsheets a day and its always the same columns that it won't read. Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it's fairly common to have invisible characters or extra whitespace when dealing with excel files. Try with `column.str.contains('Yes')`

Comment: Agreed, you probably have whitespace somewhere in the string: `" No"` does not equal `"No"`

Comment: The same problem with some whitespaces can be ture for the column name `"Unnamed: 17"`. Because you don't use `iloc` or `loc` to address the columns, it is sometimes not clear what will match. Pandas trys to find a column first and if there is no match it trys to find a row. Guess this is what is happening in the second example.

Comment: @Yuca thank-you for your help, I really appreciate the quick response. Yes that worked, I just had to add `na=False`, otherwise I was getting a ValueError, Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is some white spaces in the `Yes/No` values.

Select all the `object` (/string) columns and use [**`pandas.Series.str.strip`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) :

```
df_obj = df.select_dtypes(['object'])

df[df_obj.columns] = df_obj.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())

df.loc[(df["Unnamed: 17"] == "Yes")]
```